# when "button-press-event" will be called in gtk+?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I need an event which handles clicks on main window of my program.
I used *`button-press-event`* but when i click on my window nothing happens.

I'm designing my GUI using **Glade Interface Designer**.
please explain for me when *`button-press-event`* will be called in gtk+ & is it the event i need or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you've got the button press event mask set for the window under the 
Window Properties - Common tab in glade

Answer (score 0):

'button-press-event' should give you mouse button presses. It may be that you need to use `gtk_widget_add_device_events ()` to add button presses to the list of events that are received by the window but I think it should get them by default, can you post you code please?